# Add a name to JsonArray or JsonObject using Java [ json-simple.jar library]

Tags: java, json, json-simple

First of all i am using `json-simple-2.1.2.jar`[ [Link on GitHub](https://cliftonlabs.github.io/json-simple/) ].

It is similar to `json-simple-1.1.1.jar` but some classes are updated and some some other are deprecated but the logic is the same.

---

**Java code** [It produces the below]

```
 //JSON Array [ROOT]
    JsonArray json = new JsonArray();

    //Libraries Array
    JsonArray libraries = new JsonArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
        object.put("name", "library->" + i);
        libraries.add(object);
    }

    //Add to ROOT ARRAY
    json.add(libraries);

    //Write to File
    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter(jsonFilePath)) {
        file.write(json.toJson());
        file.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();       
    }
```

Produced `json` file:

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "library->0"
        },
        {
            "name": "library->1"
        }
    ]
]
```

**What i want**:

```
[   
  "libraries":[
        {
            "name": "library->0"
        },
        {
            "name": "library->1"
        }
    ]
]
```

As you can see `JsonArray` has a name for example : `"libraries"` .

I can't find any way to do this with neither of json-simple.jar i use.

Help is a lot appreciated :)

Comment: what you want is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @Srikanth A  Have a look here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_syntax.htm :) Let me know why you think it is wrong , i am new to JSON .

Comment: I referred here to confirm the expected JSON is invalid http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @Srikanth A  Omg i was doing the same thing :) . Strange though why it is not valid ... But in JSON you can have names for Arrays and Objects i mean :)

Comment: yes, you can have names for Array - But JSON starting is not flower braces. Just change the start and end as Flower braces, it would be a valid JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expected JSON format expected in question is not a valid JSON. It can be verified here JSONLINT.com

If you replace the starting and angular brackets to Flower brackets, it would be valid JSON. PFB code to build the same.

```
import org.json.simple.JsonArray;
import org.json.simple.JsonObject;

import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws FileNotFoundException {

        //JSON Array [ROOT]
        JsonObject finalOutput = new JsonObject();

        //Libraries Array
        JsonArray libraries = new JsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
            object.put("name", "library->" + i);
            libraries.add(object);
        }

        finalOutput.put("libraries", libraries);

        //Write to File
        try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\b21677\\output.json")) {
            file.write(finalOutput.toJson());
            file.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you veeeery much my friend! :)

Comment: Anytime friend :). Refer here http://json.org/ for precise idea on JSON.

Comment: I would upvote +2 if i could :) One more question.. What is the best JSON Library to use for Java in your opinion?